# How to define a table without primary key with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table that does not have a `primary key`. And I really do not want to apply this constraint to this table.

In *SQLAlchemy*, I defined the table class by:

```
class SomeTable(Base):
  __table__ = Table('SomeTable', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

When I try to query this table, I got:

```
ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|SomeTable|SomeTable could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'SomeTable'.
```

How to loss the constraint that every table must have a primary key?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is only one way that I know of to circumvent the primary key constraint in SQL Alchemy - it's to map specific column or columns to your table as a primary keys, even if they aren't primary key themselves.
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/ormconfiguration.html#how-do-i-map-a-table-that-has-no-primary-key.

Comment: can you give me an example of any sort. neither strings nor variables are working for me.

Comment: What about if the table has duplicate rows and you can't add an additional key column to the database?

Comment: @justin-raymond Then the table cannot be (cleanly) mapped using an ORM, as it has to be able to uniquely map an object to a row in the table. In SQLAlchemy you'd then operate on the table using the lower level `Table` construct from Core.

Comment: The table could still be cleanly mapped if the ORM selected `rowid` or `ctid` or something in absence of a specified primary key, right? Not having an official primary key shouldn't be a dealbreaker for ORMs, it just means someone doesn't care about having duplicates and doesn't need to formally distinguish between them.

Comment: If you make a column primary in model, but if you have duplicate values in databse; in this case when you will query the table and filter for any duplicate value,  it will only gives you first row. (may be because sqlalchemy assumes that column is primary so only 1 value is there)

Answer (score 21):

There is no proper solution for this but there are workarounds for it:

## Workaround 1

Adding parameter primary_key to the existing column that is not having a primary key will work.

```
class SomeTable(Base):
    __table__ = 'some_table'
    some_other_already_existing_column = Column(..., primary_key=True) # just add primary key to it whether or not this column is having primary key or not
```

## Workaround 2

Just declare a new dummy column on the **ORM layer, not in actual DB**. Just define in SQLalchemy model

```
class SomeTable(Base):
    __table__ = 'some_table'
    column_not_exist_in_db = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) # just add for sake of this error, dont add in db
```

Comment: I have a similar, but different, scenario. I created a VIEW, which doesn't have a PK. And because it has outer joins, I can't make a compound key from the various primary keys. I tried both of these workarounds, and thought I'd comment on the results.

Workaround 1. This keeps only the distinct values of the specified column. E.g. if the already-existing-column is a Boolean, only 2 rows (at most) will come back.

Workaround 2. As soon as I try to retrieve the data, it gives an error that column_not_exist doesn't exist.

I'm still looking for a solution for VIEWs. Cheers.

Comment: If I do this with oracle I get Database Exception (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00904: "PAY"."ID": invalid identifier when I go to write

Comment: Just ran into same as @Daniel'Dang'Griffith... As I'm using a series of materialized views, adding `primary_key=True` to all columns is still problematic because dupes are possible, so it omits all but the first one... For some views I could just select another column that's guaranteed unique, but for others I actually just added a `row_number() over()` to the view definition as a fake id in lieu of a sequence.

Comment: This MUST be the accepted answer in my view

Answer (score 6):

## Disclaimer: Oracle only

Oracle databases secretly store something called `rowid` to uniquely define each record in a table, even if the table doesn't have a primary key. I solved my lack of primary key problem (which I did *not* cause!) by constructing my ORM object like:

```
class MyTable(Base)
    __tablename__ = 'stupid_poorly_designed_table'
    
    rowid = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    column_a = Column(String)
    column_b = Column(String)
    ...
```

You can see what `rowid` actually looks like (it's a hex value I believe) by running

```
SELECT rowid FROM stupid_poorly_designed_table
GO
```

Comment: Postgres also has this notion with OID, but Postgres doesn't automatically create them. I'm not sure what circumstances cause OIDs to be created apart from making a table with `WITH OID`

Comment: You can not create a table with this using cx_Oracle, and when you go to write it you get "Database Exception Instance <XXX at 0x26d22cd3a20> has a NULL identity key.  If this is an auto-generated value, check that the database table allows generation of new primary key values, and that the mapped Column object is configured to expect these generated values.  Ensure also that this flush() is not occurring at an inappropriate time, such as within a load() event. adding"

Comment: @CrabbyPete Yeah you may be correct. This is still useful though for those who aren't managing the database with the ORM (which is debatably a good idea). So if the table already exists and was created by some DBA 1000mi away, this should work.

Answer (score 6):

**MSSQL Tested**

I know this thread is ancient but I spent way too long getting this to work to not share it :)

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, event
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import Integer

class RowID(Column):
    pass


@compiles(RowID)
def compile_mycolumn(element, compiler, **kw):
    return "row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))"


@event.listens_for(Table, "after_parent_attach")
def after_parent_attach(target, parent):
    if not target.primary_key:
        # if no pkey create our own one based on returned rowid
        # this is untested for writing stuff - likely wont work
        logging.info("No pkey defined for table, using rownumber %s", target)
        target.append_column(RowID('row_id', Integer, primary_key=True))
```

Comment: This answer is the best if you are using reflection

Comment: The only solution that works for me with Trino and AWS Glue.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example using `__mapper_args__` and [a synthetic primary_key](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/faq/ormconfiguration.html#how-do-i-map-a-table-that-has-no-primary-key). Because the table is time-series oriented data, there is no need for a primary key. All rows can be unique addresses with a (timestamp, pair) tuple.

```py
class Candle(Base):

    __tablename__ = "ohlvc_candle"

    __table_args__ = (
        sa.UniqueConstraint('pair_id', 'timestamp'),
    )

    #: Start second of the candle
    timestamp = sa.Column(sa.TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable=False)

    open = sa.Column(sa.Float, nullable=False)
    close = sa.Column(sa.Float, nullable=False)
    high = sa.Column(sa.Float, nullable=False)
    low = sa.Column(sa.Float, nullable=False)
    volume = sa.Column(sa.Float, nullable=False)

    pair_id = sa.Column(sa.ForeignKey("pair.id"), nullable=False)
    pair = orm.relationship(Pair,
                        backref=orm.backref("candles",
                                        lazy="dynamic",
                                        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
                                        single_parent=True, ), )

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "primary_key": [pair_id, timestamp]
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

https://docs-sqlalchemy-org.translate.goog/en/14/faq/ormconfiguration.html?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=ru&_x_tr_hl=ru#how-do-i-map-a-table-that-has-no-primary-key

One way from there:
In SQLAlchemy ORM, to map to a specific table, there must be at least one column designated as the primary key column; multi-column composite primary keys are of course also perfectly possible. These columns do not need to be known to the database as primary key columns. The columns only need to behave like a primary key, such as a non-nullable unique identifier for a row.

my code:

```
from ..meta import Base, Column, Integer, Date


class ActiveMinutesByDate(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_computer_active_minutes_by_date"

    user_computer_id = Column(Integer(), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    user_computer_date_check = Column(Date(), default=None,  primary_key=True)
    user_computer_active_minutes = Column(Integer(), nullable=True)
```

Comment: This doesn't address the use-case described in the question, where no columns satisfy `primary_key=True`.

Answer (score -3):

The solution I found is to add an auto-incrementing primary key column to the table, then use that as your primary key. The database should deal with everything else beyond that.

Comment: This is not an acceptable answer, please present them with code to fix their issue.

Comment: The OP said `And I really do not want to apply this constraint to this table.`