# SqlAlchemy not returning all rows when querying table object, but returns all rows when I query table object column

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

**Update - Solution Below**

I am extremely new to SqlAlchemy so please excuse if this is an obvious problem.
When I query the Table object I only get one result (the first in the database, there are 600+ with my filter). When I query by a column on the table it returns all the data I expect. What I am doing incorrectly?

Only returns 1 result should be hundreds

```
for row in edb_alchemy.session.query(FtSite).filter(FtSite.serial_si == 200134444):
        print(row.s_sequence)
```

Result looks like:
1

Returns all results

```
for row in edb_alchemy.session.query(FtSite.s_sequence).filter(FtSite.serial_si == 200134444):
        print(row)
```

Result looks like:
(1,)
(2,)
(3,)
(4,)...

Returns 1 result for FtSite table and all results for column

```
for row in edb_alchemy.session.query(FtSite, FtSite.s_sequence).filter(FtSite.serial_si == 200134444):
        print(row.FtSite.s_sequence, row.s_sequence)
```

Result looks like
(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1,4)....

The SQL that SQLAlchemy says its using is

```
"SELECT ft_site.serial_si AS ft_site_serial_si, ft_site.partition_id AS ft_site_partition_id, ft_site.s_sequence AS ft_site_s_sequence, ft_site.value AS ft_site_value" + \
    " FROM ft_site" + \
    " WHERE ft_site.serial_si = 200134444"
```

Which works fine as I'd expect when just using SQL query outside of SQLAlchemy.

---

**Update**

Thank you Ilja in the comments. 
For some reason I thought this table had an id primary key. 
It does not, I'm just a consumer of this db and should have been more observant.
You were correct. This table has no unique key and lists MUL under FtSite.serial_si.

This is what the table actually looks like.

```
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| p_id       | int(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| serial_si  | int(10)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| s_sequence | int(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| value      | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My original table description was

```
class FtSite(Base):
    __tablename__ = "ft_site"

    id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    serial_si = Column(INTEGER)
    partition_id = Column(INTEGER)
    s_sequence = Column(INTEGER)
    value = Column(DOUBLE)
```

I changed this to have a composite key in SQLAlchemy (s_sequence, serial_si) is unique even if it's not defined in the database. Is this the best way to handle this in SQLAlchemy? It's now returning expected results.

```
class FtSite(Base):
    __tablename__ = "ft_site"

    serial_si = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    partition_id = Column(INTEGER)
    s_sequence = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(DOUBLE)
```

Comment: Could you post your class definition for `FtSite`?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you have a non unique "primary key", e.g. your declarative class definition differs from the actual table definition in your database. That's why when querying for model object instances you get a single result (SQLAlchemy cannot differentiate them), but when querying for columns you get the actual row values.

Comment: Your solution code samples highlight the problem so it is easy to understand, thank you

Answer (score 24):

I ran into a similar situation where SQLAlchemy query object's `.all()` doesn't return all the rows in the table (always missing some) but `.count()` call does give the correct count. After digging into it a bit more, I realized that the model declaration deviated from the actual table schema in that database. First, the database has a single primary key column in the schema but the model declaration has a composition primary key (in reverse case like yours), also I missed a 3-column unique constraint where as the table schema has it.

What happened there in my case was that whenever SQL Alchemy query the database it did get all the rows behind the scene but due to the incorrect composition primary key in my model declaration has prevented some rows loading into SQLAlchemy's session (primary keys by definition uniquely indentify the objects and it won't load two objects with the same primary key in session as a result, hence it tosses out those composition columns that have same values even in the database they do have different PKs.)

In conclusion, double check model declaration with database schema to make sure they are in sync is the first response from this kind of issues.

Comment: @Deny, thank you a lot, you saved me a few hours

Comment: This also saved me from some really hard confusion. Thank you! Copying the SQLAlchemy created query returned the correct result in the DB directly. That means, that SQLAlchemy puts more logic on the result after querying the DB. Not sure if I like that, but at least now I know.

Answer (score 0):

It is a schema mismatch with primary key specified in the SQLAlchemy model and none in the underlying database table.

From the [SQLAlchemy ORM](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/faq/ormconfiguration.html#how-do-i-map-a-table-that-has-no-primary-key) docs:

> Most ORMs require that objects have some kind of primary key defined because the object in memory must correspond to a uniquely identifiable row in the database table

The solution is to define a composite primary key:

```
 class SomeClass(Base):
     __tablename__ = "some_table_with_no_pk"

     uid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
-    bar = Column(String)
+    bar = Column(String, primary_key=True)
```

A related primary key question: [How to define a table without primary key with SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34283259/175584)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, whatever Devy mentioned is correct. I faced the same issue and it got resolved. Please check the SQLAlchemy model declaration and database schema. If you want to quickly check that by using "Sqlacodegen"

```
sqlacodegen --outfile models.py mysql+pymysql://<username><password>@<hostname/ip of database>:<dbport>/<databasename>
```

https://pypi.org/project/sqlacodegen/ (Check this for more information).

Please let me know if you need anything.