# Troubleshooting uncooperative For Loop of SQLalchemy results

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Looking for a second set of eyes here.  I cannot figure out why the following loop will not continue past the first iteration.

The 'servicestocheck' sqlalchemy query returns 45 rows in my test, but I cannot iterate through the results like I'm expecting... and no errors are returned.  All of the functionality works on the first iteration.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
def serviceAssociation(current_contact_id,perm_contact_id):


    servicestocheck = oracleDB.query(PORTAL_CONTACT).filter(
    PORTAL_CONTACT.contact_id == current_contact_id 
    ).order_by(PORTAL_CONTACT.serviceID).count()

    print(servicestocheck)  # returns 45 items

    servicestocheck = oracleDB.query(PORTAL_CONTACT).filter(
    PORTAL_CONTACT.contact_id = current_contact_id
    ).order_by(PORTAL_CONTACT.serviceID).all()


    for svc in servicestocheck:



    #
        # Check to see if already exists
        #

        check_existing_association = mysqlDB.query( 
        CONTACTTOSERVICE).filter(CONTACTTOSERVICE.contact_id ==
        perm_contact_id,CONTACTTOSERVICE.serviceID ==
        svc.serviceID).first()

        # 
        # If no existing association
        #

        if check_existing_association is None:


            print ("Prepare Association")

            assoc_contact_id = perm_contact_id
            assoc_serviceID = svc.serviceID
            assoc_role_billing = False
            assoc_role_technical = False
            assoc_role_commercial = False


            if svc.contact_type == 'Billing':
                assoc_role_billing = True
            if svc.contact_type == 'Technical':
                assoc_role_technical = True
            if svc.contact_type == 'Commercial':
                assoc_role_commercial = True

            try:
                newAssociation = CONTACTTOSERVICE(
                assoc_contact_id, assoc_serviceID,
                assoc_role_billing,assoc_role_technical,
                assoc_role_commercial)

                mysqlDB.add(newAssociation)
                mysqlDB.commit()
                mysqlDB.flush()

            except Exception as e:

                print(e)
```

This function is called from a script, and it is called from within another loop.  I can't find any issues with nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being an issue with SQLAlchemy ORM (see [SqlAlchemy not returning all rows when querying table object, but returns all rows when I query table object column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38495291/sqlalchemy-not-returning-all-rows-when-querying-table-object-but-returns-all-ro))

I think the issue is due to one of my tables above does not have a primary key in real life, and adding a fake one did not help.  (I don't have access to the DB to add a key)

Rather than fight it further... I went ahead and wrote [raw SQL](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-execute-raw-sql-in-sqlalchemy/) to move my project along.

This did the trick:

```
    query = 'SELECT * FROM PORTAL_CONTACT WHERE contact_id = ' + str(current_contact_id) + 'ORDER BY contact_id ASC'

    servicestocheck = oracleDB.execute(query)
```

Comment: This is not an issue with the ORM. The ORM *requires* that your rows are uniquely identifiable, i.e. have a proper key.